# unable to highlight navigation menu

Tags: html, css

I have a menu with four elements say A , B , c and D

I want to highlight particular Element say A ,

I have my HTML and CSS like this

```css
div.smenu div a {
  padding:5px 10px;
  display:block;
  border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
  color:#3c8287;
  background-color:#fff
}

div.smenu div a.current {
  background-color:#EEE;
  color:#3c8287;
  font-weight:700
}

div.smenu div a:hover {
  color:#3c8287;
  text-decoration:none;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:right center;
  font-weight:700;
  background-color:#EEE
}
```

```html
<div class="smenu">
  <table>
    . . . .
    <div>
      <span>Create request for</span>

      <a href="xyz/abc/dosomething!inputa.action">A</a>
      <a href="xyz/abc/dosomething!inputb.action">B</a>

    </div>
    <div>
      <span>Direct access to</span>
      <a href="xyz/abc/dosomething!inputc.action">C</a>
      <a href="xyz/abc/dosomething!inputd.action">D</a>
    </div>
  </table>
</div>
```

and should remain as highlighted as long i stay on  "A"

In "A" , i have tasks to "edit"( where edit is a hyper link in that page)
something like

```
<a href="............" >edit</a>
```

now, when i click on this edit link, my highlight(bold) on "A" disappears

Any help in fixing this, would be really apprecieated
thanks in advance!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited

Comment: It may be the :visited selector you are looking for

Comment: thanks for reply!
i tried with :visited, dint work either :'(

Comment: Note that one should try to put a navigation in a list. That's the semantically logical choice.

Answer (score 0):

Set a div around every  element and use that to trigger it:

```
<div class="smenu">
<table>
.
.
.
.
.
<span>Create request for</span>

                                <div class="menu-item"><a href="xyz/abc/dosomething!inputa.action">A</a><div>
                                <div class="menu-item"><a href="xyz/abc/dosomething!inputb.action">B</a><div>

                            </div>
                            <div >
                                <span>Direct access to</span>    
                                <div class="menu-item"><a href="xyz/abc/dosomething!inputc.action">C</a><div>
                                <div class="menu-item"><a href="xyz/abc/dosomething!inputd.action">D</a></div>
```

Do the css like this:

```
.menu-item a : hover
{
    color: #3c8287;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right center;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
}
```

This is how I usually do it without any issues.

Also it might indeed be best to not forget the 'visited' or try clearing ur cache.
Hope you can get it to work.

Cheers

Comment: my :hover works fine, its just that i want the particular menu item to be highlighted , as long as i work under that page ....
thanks fr  suggetions, ill clear cache and check.

Comment: You could add it with javascript. Add an extra section to the class called 'active'. This way you can simply do '.menu-item.active' and set the color.

it might even be easier to use lists:
.csmenu ul > li:active{
    ...
}

Answer (score 0):

It's because you never use your css class `current`

Let's say you are on page A, you should add the class `current`  to the A menu element like this :

```css
div.smenu div a {
    padding:5px 10px;
    display:block;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
    color:#3c8287;
    background-color:#fff
}

div.smenu div a.current {
    background-color:#EEE;
    color:#3c8287;
    font-weight:700
}

div.smenu div a:hover {
    color:#3c8287;
    text-decoration:none;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:right center;
    font-weight:700;
    background-color:#EEE
}
```

```html
<div class="smenu">
    <table>
        . . . .
        <div>
            <span>Create request for</span>

            <a class="current" href="xyz/abc/dosomething!inputa.action">A</a>
            <a href="xyz/abc/dosomething!inputb.action">B</a>

        </div>
        <div>
            <span>Direct access to</span>
            <a href="xyz/abc/dosomething!inputc.action">C</a>
            <a href="xyz/abc/dosomething!inputd.action">D</a>
        </div>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Note : `background-position` and `backgrond-repeat` are useless here

Comment: Thanks fr giving me an idea...
If i do this, then e1 when my "A" is not clicked, it would be Highlighted rite?
I want A to be highlighted, nly wen i click on it, and it should remain being highlighted as long as im on that page

Comment: you have to deal with javascript (and for example `onclick` handlers) to add or remove the class "current" when needed